# Angular 4.3 HttpClient Response Obj

Tags: angular

I've been switching my services to the new HttpClient from Angular 4.3.

```
return this._http.get<ValidateEmailResponse>(`${_validateEmailApi}`, { params })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

However, the response is of type `<Object>` and not of `<ValidateEmailResponse>`

such as;

[image]

Should it not be  as declared?

Comment: What tool is providing that message? Does it list all objects like that? Because on the prior line it seems to display the correct type.

Comment: Within the browser, but from my screen shot that is within VSCode debugger. I've added a simple console.log for instance of ValidateEmailResponse after the success, and it skips the log. The prior line as the picture is just a console log ValidateEmailResponse success --> object.

Answer (score 2):

This is what my code now looks like with the new 4.3 HttpClient (see below). Notice the return type of my method.

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this._productUrl)
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
        // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: My Method returns Observable<ValidateEmailResponse> 

But it is still returning Object.

I have not tried: .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))

As I do not believe I need this.

Comment: No, you don't need `do`. That's just for debugging.

Comment: This helped me out solving my incompatible types error for the catch :)

Comment: Is there an import statement for `Error` from `err.error instanceof Error`, I've been having trouble getting `if` branch to fire when disabling the network in Chrome, which I thought would be of type `Error`