# Catching errors in Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, rest, angular-httpclient

I have a data service that looks like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost'
        constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }
    get(url, params): Promise<Object> {

        return this.sendRequest(this.baseUrl + url, 'get', null, params)
            .map((res) => {
                return res as Object
            })
            .toPromise();
    }
    post(url, body): Promise<Object> {
        return this.sendRequest(this.baseUrl + url, 'post', body)
            .map((res) => {
                return res as Object
            })
            .toPromise();
    }
    patch(url, body): Promise<Object> {
        return this.sendRequest(this.baseUrl + url, 'patch', body)
            .map((res) => {
                return res as Object
            })
            .toPromise();
    }
    sendRequest(url, type, body, params = null): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient[type](url, { params: params }, body)
    }
}
```

If I get an HTTP error (i.e. 404), I get a nasty console message:
**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]** from **core.es5.js** 
How do I handle it in my case?

Answer (score 343, accepted):

You have some options, depending on your needs. If you want to handle errors on a per-request basis, add a `catch` to your request. If you want to add a global solution, use `HttpInterceptor`.

Open [**here the working demo plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ulFGp4VMzrbaDJeGqc6q?p=preview) for the solutions below.

## tl;dr

In the simplest case, you'll just need to add a `.catch()` or a `.subscribe()`, like:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; // don't forget this, or you'll get a runtime error
this.httpClient
      .get("data-url")
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // simple logging, but you can do a lot more, see below
        console.error('An error occurred:', err.error);
      });

// or
this.httpClient
      .get("data-url")
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log('success', data),
        error => console.log('oops', error)
      );
```

But there are more details to this, see below.

## Method (local) solution: log error and return fallback response

If you need to handle errors in only one place, you can use `catch` and return a default value (or empty response) instead of failing completely. You also don't need the `.map` just to cast, you can use a generic function. Source: [Angular.io - Getting Error Details](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details).

So, a generic `.get()` method, would be like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry'; // don't forget the imports

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    // notice the <T>, making the method generic
    get<T>(url, params): Observable<T> {
      return this.httpClient
          .get<T>(this.baseUrl + url, {params})
          .retry(3) // optionally add the retry
          .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
              // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
              console.error('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
            } else {
              // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
              // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
              console.error(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
            }

            // ...optionally return a default fallback value so app can continue (pick one)
            // which could be a default value
            // return Observable.of<any>({my: "default value..."});
            // or simply an empty observable
            return Observable.empty<T>();
          });
     }
}
```

Handling the error will allow you app to continue even when the service at the URL is in bad condition.

This per-request solution is good mostly when you want to return a specific default response to each method. But if you only care about error displaying (or have a global default response), the better solution is to use an interceptor, as described below.

Run the [**working demo plunker here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ulFGp4VMzrbaDJeGqc6q?p=preview).

## Advanced usage: Intercepting all requests or responses

Once again, [Angular.io guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses) shows:

> A major feature of `@angular/common/http` is interception, the ability to declare interceptors which sit in between your application and the backend. When your application makes a request, interceptors transform it before sending it to the server, and the interceptors can transform the response on its way back before your application sees it. This is useful for everything from authentication to logging.

Which, of course, can be used to handle errors in a very simple way ([**demo plunker here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ulFGp4VMzrbaDJeGqc6q?p=preview)):

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse,
         HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry'; // don't forget the imports

@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.error('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.error(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
        }

        // ...optionally return a default fallback value so app can continue (pick one)
        // which could be a default value (which has to be a HttpResponse here)
        // return Observable.of(new HttpResponse({body: [{name: "Default value..."}]}));
        // or simply an empty observable
        return Observable.empty<HttpEvent<any>>();
      });
  }
}
```

**Providing your interceptor:** Simply declaring the `HttpErrorInterceptor` above doesn't cause your app to use it. You need to [wire it up in your app module](https://angular.io/guide/http#providing-your-interceptor) by providing it as an interceptor, as follows:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorInterceptor } from './path/http-error.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  }],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Note:** If you have *both* an error interceptor and some local error handling, naturally, it is likely that no local error handling will ever be triggered, since the error will always be handled by the interceptor *before* it reaches the local error handling.

Run the [**working demo plunker here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ulFGp4VMzrbaDJeGqc6q?p=preview).

Comment: well, if he wants to be fully fancy he would leave his service fully clear: `return this.httpClient.get<type>(...)`. and then have `catch...` somewhere out of the service where he actually consumes it because thats where he will be building observables flow and can handle it best.

Comment: return Observable.of(e); worked for me
This way I can defer the exception handle to the caller

Comment: I agree, maybe an optimal solution would be to have the `Promise<Object>`'s client (the caller of the `DataService`'s methods) to handle the error. Example: `this.dataService.post('url', {...}).then(...).catch((e) => console.log('handle error here instead', e));`. Choose whatever is clearer to you and your service's users.

Comment: This doesn't compile: ```return Observable.of({my: "default value..."});```

It gives an error "|...' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'."

Comment: @YakovFain If you want a default value in the interceptor, it must be a `HttpEvent`, such as a `HttpResponse`. So, for instance, you could use: `return Observable.of(new HttpResponse({body: [{name: "Default value..."}]}));`. I have updated the answer to make this point clear. Also, I created a working demo plunker to show everything working: https://plnkr.co/edit/ulFGp4VMzrbaDJeGqc6q?p=preview

Comment: @acdcjunior, you are a gift that keeps on giving :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the `${err.error}`  gives me: `body was: [object Object]` Do you any clue about this?

Comment: Here is a clue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595328/angular-4-3-httpclient-response-obj)

Comment: Simple as hell, go with this one

Comment: This answer needs a big update in terms of importing for rxjs

Comment: @PaulKruger would you point me some resources for that so I can update the answer? I haven't been using the newest rxjs.

Comment: Check the answer below from @MegaCasper, I am not 100% sure what needs to change but I know that your code is very outdated unfortunately :)

Comment: @acdcjunior can you please update your answer, catch() is deprecated and they are using catchError() currently, and don't forgot to add pipe for chaining operators :D

Comment: @RebaiAhmed do you have more pointers for that? I will update the answer, but I haven't used Angular recently

Comment: Although specified in the docs the client side error should be error.error instance of ProgressEvent, see here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34748

Answer (score 165):

Let me please update the [acdcjunior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850609/acdcjunior)'s answer about using [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) with the latest RxJs features(v.6).

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, EMPTY, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.error instanceof Error) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: ${error.error}`);
        }

        // If you want to return a new response:
        //return of(new HttpResponse({body: [{name: "Default value..."}]}));

        // If you want to return the error on the upper level:
        //return throwError(error);

        // or just return nothing:
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This needs to get upvoted more. acdcjunior's answer is unusable as of today

Comment: Although specified in the docs the client side error should be error.error instance of ProgressEvent, see here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34748

Comment: `throwError(error)` seems to be deprecated now, but using `throwError(() => error)` isn't for whatever reason.

Answer (score 53):

With the arrival of the `HTTPClient` API, not only was the `Http` API replaced, but a new one was added, the `HttpInterceptor` API.

AFAIK one of its goals is to add default behavior to all the HTTP outgoing requests and incoming responses.

So assumming that you want to add a **default error handling behavior**, adding `.catch()` to all of your possible http.get/post/etc methods is ridiculously hard to maintain.

This could be done in the following way as example using a `HttpInterceptor`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

/**
 * Intercepts the HTTP responses, and in case that an error/exception is thrown, handles it
 * and extract the relevant information of it.
 */
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    /**
     * Intercepts an outgoing HTTP request, executes it and handles any error that could be triggered in execution.
     * @see HttpInterceptor
     * @param req the outgoing HTTP request
     * @param next a HTTP request handler
     */
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req)
            .catch(errorResponse => {
                let errMsg: string;
                if (errorResponse instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    const err = errorResponse.message || JSON.stringify(errorResponse.error);
                    errMsg = `${errorResponse.status} - ${errorResponse.statusText || ''} Details: ${err}`;
                } else {
                    errMsg = errorResponse.message ? errorResponse.message : errorResponse.toString();
                }
                return _throw(errMsg);
            });
    }
}

/**
 * Provider POJO for the interceptor
 */
export const ErrorInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true,
};
```

// app.module.ts

```js
import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from 'somewhere/in/your/src/folder';

@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [
    ...
    ErrorInterceptorProvider,
    ....
   ],
   ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Some extra info for OP: Calling http.get/post/etc without a strong type isn't an optimal use of the API. Your service should look like this:

```js
// These interfaces could be somewhere else in your src folder, not necessarily in your service file
export interface FooPost {
 // Define the form of the object in JSON format that your 
 // expect from the backend on post
}

export interface FooPatch {
 // Define the form of the object in JSON format that your 
 // expect from the backend on patch
}

export interface FooGet {
 // Define the form of the object in JSON format that your 
 // expect from the backend on get
}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost'
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    get(url, params): Observable<FooGet> {

        return this.http.get<FooGet>(this.baseUrl + url, params);
    }

    post(url, body): Observable<FooPost> {
        return this.http.post<FooPost>(this.baseUrl + url, body);
    }

    patch(url, body): Observable<FooPatch> {
        return this.http.patch<FooPatch>(this.baseUrl + url, body);
    }
}
```

Returning `Promises` from your service methods instead of `Observables` is another bad decision.

And an extra piece of advice: if you are using **TYPE**script, then start using the type part of it. You lose one of the biggest advantages of the language: to know the type of the value that you are dealing with.

If you want a, in my opinion, good example of an angular service, take a look [at the following gist](https://gist.github.com/jotatoledo/a7cddc2abd0e2bbdceb9db22d2ae6ed9).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153612/discussion-on-answer-by-jota-toledo-catching-errors-in-angular-httpclient).

Comment: I assume this should be `this.http.get()` etc. and not `this.get()` etc. in `DataService`?

Comment: The selected answer appears to now be more complete.

Answer (score 35):

For Angular 6+ , .catch doesn't work directly with Observable. You have to use

```js
.pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
```

Below code:

```js
import { IEmployee } from './interfaces/employee';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  private url = '/assets/data/employee.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.url)
                    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));  // catch error
  }

  /** Error Handling method */

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

For more details, refer to the [Angular Guide for Http](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. The others give an error of: "Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>".

Comment: Although specified in the docs the client side error should be error.error instance of ProgressEvent, see here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34748

Answer (score 15):

Fairly straightforward (in compared to how it was done with the previous API).

Source from (copy and pasted) the [Angular official guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling)

```
 http
  .get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items')
  .subscribe(
    // Successful responses call the first callback.
    data => {...},
    // Errors will call this callback instead:
    err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong!');
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 8):

**Angular 8 HttpClient Error Handling Service [Example](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-8-httpclient-service-tutorial-to-consume-restfull-api-from-server/)**

[image]

**api.service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Student } from '../model/student';
    import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ApiService {

      // API path
      base_path = 'http://localhost:3000/students';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      // Http Options
      httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
      }

      // Handle API errors
      handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.error(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
            `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        // return an observable with a user-facing error message
        return throwError(
          'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
      };


      // Create a new item
      createItem(item): Observable<Student> {
        return this.http
          .post<Student>(this.base_path, JSON.stringify(item), this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(
            retry(2),
            catchError(this.handleError)
          )
      }

     ........
     ........

    }
```

Comment: Although specified in the docs the client side error should be error.error instance of ProgressEvent, see here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34748

Answer (score 5):

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const PASSENGER_API = 'api/passengers';

getPassengers(): Observable<Passenger[]> {
  return this.http
    .get<Passenger[]>(PASSENGER_API)
    .pipe(catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(error)));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

on Angular 13

```
      this.callApiSrvice.GetProducts()
    .subscribe({
      next: (data) => 
      {
        this.products = data;
      },
      error: (e) => 
      {
        
        console.log('Error while loading the product data');
      }      
    })
```

Comment: Some of the subscribe arguments have been deprecated in favor of using partial observers as shown in the sample above. See: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments for more background info.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have something like this:

```
this.sendRequest(...)
.map(...)
.catch((err) => {
//handle your error here
})
```

It highly depends also how do you use your service but this is the basic case.

Answer (score 1):

Following @acdcjunior answer, this is how I implemented it

service:

```
  get(url, params): Promise<Object> {

            return this.sendRequest(this.baseUrl + url, 'get', null, params)
                .map((res) => {
                    return res as Object
                }).catch((e) => {
                    return Observable.of(e);
                })
                .toPromise();
        }
```

caller:

```
this.dataService.get(baseUrl, params)
            .then((object) => {
                if(object['name'] === 'HttpErrorResponse') {
                            this.error = true;
                           //or any handle
                } else {
                    this.myObj = object as MyClass 
                }
           });
```

Comment: Why you're using Promise instead of Observable!

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself unable to catch errors with any of the solutions provided here, it may be that the server isn't handling CORS requests.

In that event, Javascript, much less Angular, can access the error information.

Look for warnings in your console that include `CORB` or `Cross-Origin Read Blocking`.

Also, the syntax has changed for handling errors (as described in every other answer). You now use pipe-able operators, like so:

```
this.service.requestsMyInfo(payload).pipe(
    catcheError(err => {
        // handle the error here.
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using Interceptor you can catch error. Below is code:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    //Get Auth Token from Service which we want to pass thr service call
    const authToken: any = `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('jwtToken')}`
    // Clone the service request and alter original headers with auth token.
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Authorization', authToken)
    });
 
    const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'Authorization': authToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} });

    // Send cloned request with header to the next handler.
    return next.handle(authReq).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log("Service Response thr Interceptor");
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log("err.status", err);
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
          location.href = '/login';
          console.log("Unauthorized Request - In case of Auth Token Expired");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You can prefer [this blog](http://musttoknows.com/use-interceptor-angular-error-handling-angular-authentication-using-http-client-http-interceptor/)..given simple example for it.

Answer (score 1):

The worse thing is not having a decent stack trace which you simply cannot generate using an `HttpInterceptor` (hope to stand corrected). All you get is a load of zone and rxjs useless bloat, and not the line or class that generated the error.

To do this you will need to generate a stack in an extended `HttpClient`, so its not advisable to do this in a production environment.

```
/**
 * Extended HttpClient that generates a stack trace on error when not in a production build.
 */
@Injectable()
export class TraceHttpClient extends HttpClient {
  constructor(handler: HttpHandler) {
    super(handler);
  }

  request(...args: [any]): Observable<any> {
    const stack = environment.production ? null : Error().stack;
    return super.request(...args).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        if (stack) console.error('HTTP Client error stack\n', stack);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
}
```