# Customize errors from server for front-end in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, error-handling

I need your help to recommend me documents or links that solve my question.
Actually in Angular 4, I want to customize error from api services. For example, if the server responses the request with error, the error will be shown to user. My question is how can I get all errors from server and for each ones write codes for user in front-end.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019771/catching-errors-in-angular-httpclient) this could be helpful, I recommend that you should try to add specific error code in your backend (e.g spring `@ExceptionHandler` ) and in your front end You can try to use `.catch((err: any) => {
        if(err.status == 'your code e.g 84573'){
        console.error('An special error occurred coneccted to the business logic:', err.error);
        }
      });`
This(more or less this) was working in angularjs - probably will work here too but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching errors in Angular HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019771/catching-errors-in-angular-httpclient)

Comment: @MacRyze thank you, it is so easy :)

Comment: @zgue thanks a lot, it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make HTTP interceptor and collect all server error in single service and modify them according to your requirement.

This is one of the simplest implementation I have found
https://hackernoon.com/global-http-request-error-catching-in-angular-486a319f59ab