# How to set it's return type and show related toaster in response

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on ASP.NET core Web API and I do not know how to return something when data inserted into database and then show related toaster on response type as either error or success. I've created an interface where I defined method then created service where I implement interface method and insert data to database then created controller which connect to angular.

Interface method

`void AddMurderComplian(Complians complians);`

Service method

```
public void AddMurderComplian(Complians complians)
{
    var complianMurder = new Complians()
    {
        Dead = complians.Dead,
        Wounded = complians.Wounded,
        CriminalsInvolved = complians.CriminalsInvolved,
        CriminalAppearence = complians.CriminalAppearence,
        VehiclesUsed = complians.VehiclesUsed,
        WeaponsDescription = complians.WeaponsDescription,
        SubType = complians.SubType,
        ApplicationUserId = complians.ApplicationUserId
    };
    try
    {

        _appDbContext.Complians.Add(complianMurder);
        _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("complianMurder")]
public void Post(Complians complian)
{
    _complians.AddMurderComplian(complian);
}
```

Angular

```
submitMurderInfo()
{
    this.formModelMurder.SubType = "Murder";
    this.formModelMurder.ApplicationUserId = sessionStorage.getItem("Id");
    this.murderService.murderQuestionnaire(this.formModelMurder).subscribe(
        (res: any)=>{
        if (res.succeeded)
        {
            //   this.toastr.success("Welome ");
            //  this.formModelMurder.Dead = '',
            //  this.formModelMurder.Wounded ='',
            //  this.formModelMurder.CriminalsInvolved = '',
            //  this.formModelMurder.CriminalAppearence = '',
            //  this.formModelMurder.VehiclesUsed = '',
            //  this.formModelMurder.WeaponsDescription ='',
            //  this.formModelMurder.SubType = '',
            //  this.formModelMurder.ApplicationUserId = ''
        }
        else
        {
            // this.toastr.error('Sorry Check your complian');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
public bool AddMurderComplian(Complians complians)
{
  bool succeeded = false;
  var complianMurder = new Complians()
  {
      Dead = complians.Dead,
      Wounded = complians.Wounded, 
      CriminalsInvolved = complians.CriminalsInvolved, 
      CriminalAppearence = complians.CriminalAppearence, 
      VehiclesUsed = complians.VehiclesUsed, 
      WeaponsDescription = complians.WeaponsDescription,
      SubType = complians.SubType,
      ApplicationUserId = complians.ApplicationUserId
  };
  try
  {
      _appDbContext.Complians.Add(complianMurder);
      _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
      succeeded = true;
      return succeeded;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      succeeded = false;
      return succeeded;
  }
}
```

In the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("complianMurder")]
public bool Post(Complians complian)
{
    return _complians.AddMurderComplian(complian);
}
```

In angular:

```
submitMurderInfo()
{
  this.formModelMurder.SubType = "Murder";
  this.formModelMurder.ApplicationUserId = sessionStorage.getItem("Id");
  this.murderService
    .murderQuestionnaire(this.formModelMurder)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      if (res) {
        // Successfully inserted
      } else {
        // this.toastr.error('Sorry Check your complian');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: will try like this and then response to you.

Comment: @parshant what will be the type of method that we defined in interface? should it be bool?

Comment: lots of thanks this show me the result what i was expecting.

Comment: @prahant one more thing . when i inserted similar data to text field mean if i define text field for integer or  string it show successfully message but if inserted string into integer then it show 400 bad request on console. how to handle this.

Comment: error:
errors: {Wounded: Array(1), CriminalsInvolved: Array(1)}
status: 400
title: "One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId: "80000009-0002-f800-b63f-84710c7967bb"
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:49601/api/Complians/complianMurder: 400 Bad Request"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"

Comment: @WasifZaman There must be an exception in the `Post` method while converting that nvarchar into integer value

Comment: @parshant why not.

Comment: public class Complians
    {
    {public int Id { get; set; }    
        public int Dead { get; set; }
        public int Wounded { get; set; }  
        public int VehiclesUsed { get; set; }
        public int NoOfPersonsInvolved { get; set; }
        public string CriminalAppearence { get; set; }
        public int CriminalsInvolved { get; set; }
        public int WeaponsUsed { get; set; }public string WeaponsDescription { get; set; }
       
    }

Comment: @WasifZaman so for what property your are sending string as a value?

Comment: i mean that if it handle the success result and show toaster then why it can not show toaster for unsuccessful .i do what you told but it can not handle bad request ..

Comment: @WasifZaman Okay, show `murderQuestionnaire` method or search *handle bad request in http in angular/ observables* or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019771/catching-errors-in-angular-httpclient) will help

Comment: murderQuestionnaire(data: any){
    let options=this.CreateBasicHeader();
     var murderBody={
       Dead: data.Dead,
       Wounded: data.Wounded,
       CriminalsInvolved: data.CriminalsInvolved,
       CriminalAppearence: data.CriminalAppearence,
       VehiclesUsed: data.VehiclesUsed,
       WeaponsDescription :data.WeaponsDescription,
       SubType :data.SubType,
       ApplicationUserId :data.ApplicationUserId
     };
     return this.http.post(this.BaseUrl + '/Complians/complianMurder' ,JSON.stringify(murderBody),options);
  }

Comment: i commented my murderquestionnaire service .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202766/discussion-between-wasif-zaman-and-prashant-pimpale).

Comment: `methodPost() {
    
    return this.http.put(url, null, { headers: this.getHeader.HTTPHeader() })
      .toPromise()
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }`