# What is correct type for error from HttpRequest in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm handling error like this:

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) : Observable<HttpError> {
    return throwError(error.error?.errors);
}
```

and i would like to set correct types but i'm not sure how to do it correct.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
export interface Error {
    data: any;
    errors: [];
    pagination: any;
}

export interface HttpError {
error: Error;
headers: any;
message: string;
name: string;
ok: boolean
status: number
statusText: string;
url: string;
}
```

But it still doesn't know what 'errors' is.

I'm getting response with following error
[image]

Comment: Can you also specify how are you consuming the handleError method ?

Comment: Just for your reference, you can checkout here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019771/catching-errors-in-angular-httpclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the official [[Angular HTTP documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details)][1](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details) to find the following code snipped (copy-pasted, not modified):

```ts
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.status === 0) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: `, error.error);
  }
  // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

Here, you can see that the class is HttpErrorResponse, which is documented [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse).

Answer (score -1):

You can get it by status code

```
500 - internal server error
200 - success
404 - method not found
400 - bad request
401 - Unauthorized
422 - Entity response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity
```

Check this for ref: https://httpstatuses.com/

For your case check `Content-type` header