# Perform action on different server responses

Tags: javascript

On the moment, I am at the point where the client can send requests to the server, have the server perform actions and send back a response to the client.

For exemple, when I want to change a password, I verify the old password in my database. If it matches, the password is updated and I send a 200 response like so :

`sendResponse("User's Password Updated", exchange, 200, true);`
which is read in chrome's network tab as : `{ "response" : "User's Password Updated"}`

If the old password is wrong (can't verify the user's identity), it sends the following message :
`sendResponse("User's password could not be verified", exchange, 200, true);`
which is read in chrome's network tab as : `{ "response" : "User's password could not be verified"}`

Now what I want to do is to perform a different action on my client for each action. For this exemple, let's log a message.

I want to have something like that (pseudocode):

```
if (response === "User's password could not be verified")
   console.log('User's password could not be verified');
else if ( response === "User's Password Updated")
   console.log('User's Password Updated');
```

*keep in mind this is my first time using http, and I am pretty happy with myself being able to display the different responses in the network tab*

Comment: I don't see why it matters where `response` comes from. It's just a String (or Response object), and you have a conditional, which is the correct way to "do 
 actions depending on some condition"

Comment: yeah but what do I write to check the response ?

Comment: `===` is fine to check **exact text**. If you have more specific text that can change, then you'd want to use regex or otherwise parse the string

Comment: nevermind, all I want to know is what is the method that puts the response in a string, I can do the rest...

Comment: A [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object has a `body` attribute and a `text()` method

Comment: I think you should console log something based on the http code. It doesn't really make sense to send a 200 response when "User's password could not be verified" because it did not successfully auth the user. Rather send a `401` http resonse and check for that

Comment: how do I read a response code and perform an action? @user

Comment: `response.status` (should be a number not string). @OneCricketeer sent a good resource that allows you to check all the attributes on the response object.

Comment: yeah I saw it, thank you!!

Comment: No problem, please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment you should conditionally display a message based on the http response code, not message.

To do that you would modify your code to this:

```
sendResponse("User's password could not be verified", exchange, 401, true);
```

Then in your if statement you would do:

```
if (response.status === 401) {
   console.log('User's password could not be verified');
} else if ( response === 200) {
   console.log('User's Password Updated');
}
```

I suggest you read up on the response object: [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) and [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)..

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019771/catching-errors-in-angular-httpclient) also may help.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that, but my problem is that I don't know how to create the Response Object in this situation or even where to put my if statement

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I'm assuming you are using the fetch api or axios to post data to your server, correct?

Comment: I am using HttpClient in my constructor

Comment: You using angular? If so: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: I use `this.http.post(url, body, option).pipe(catchError(this.handleError(request)))` so I would like to do something similar.

the handleError function is similar to the one you answered. It is just a couple of if statements.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with angular, but I've updated my answer with a link to a similar question to yours.